# Reposition an element in an Array

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-1.8.7

Say I have...

```
arr = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

...and I want to move "a" between "b" and "c". 
I currently do

```
arr.delete("a")
arr.insert(2, "a")
```

Can I do that in a single operation?

Thanks

Comment: it has to be inplace? why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to repeat `"a"`. Put them in one:

```
arr.insert(2, arr.delete("a"))
```

Comment: Thanks! This will do the job.

Answer (score 3):

You can use parallel assignment:

```
arr[0], arr[1] = arr[1], arr[0]
=> ["b", "a"]
arr
=> ["b", "a", "c"]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to move "a" **between** "b" and "c", then you should do:

```
arr.insert(1, arr.delete_at(0))
```

※Use `.delete_at` instead of `.delete` because you may have multiple `'a'` in your array.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array#shuffle!`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Array.html#method-i-shuffle-21)

```
arr = [ "a","b","c" ] 
arr.shuffle! until arr[1] == 'a' && arr[0]=='b'
p arr #=> ["b", "a", "c"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert a after b, regardless of where they are in the array:

```
arr.insert(arr.index("b"), arr.delete_at(arr.index("a")))
=> ["b", "a", "c"]
```

You could also do:

```
 arr[arr.index("a")], arr[arr.index("b")] = "b","a"
```